# How to create a video from ARSKView (or SKView) frames, including micro audio (ios 11)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, arkit

I am playing with ARKit, and I would like to create a video from the ARSKView frames.
I tried to use ReplayKit, but the behaviour is not what I expect : 
- I don't want to record the whole screen.
- I don't want the user to be prompted we are recording the screen.

Also, how can I combine micro input and video ? As I guess the audio is not streamed in ARSKView?
Here is the code (from Apple example) :

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSKViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSKView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self

        // Show statistics such as fps and node count
        sceneView.showsFPS = true
        sceneView.showsNodeCount = true

        // Load the SKScene from 'Scene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "Scene") {
            sceneView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Create a session configuration
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration()

        // Run the view's session
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        // Pause the view's session
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    // MARK: - ARSKViewDelegate

    func view(_ view: ARSKView, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SKNode? {
        // Create and configure a node for the anchor added to the view's session.
        let labelNode = SKLabelNode(text: "")
        labelNode.horizontalAlignmentMode = .center
        labelNode.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
        return labelNode;
    }

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        // Present an error message to the user

    }

    func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
        // Inform the user that the session has been interrupted, for example, by presenting an overlay

    }

    func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
        // Reset tracking and/or remove existing anchors if consistent tracking is required

    }}
```

And in case it's necessary, the Scene class :

```
import SpriteKit
import ARKit
class Scene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // Setup your scene here
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        guard let sceneView = self.view as? ARSKView else {
            return
        }

        // Create anchor using the camera's current position
        if let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame {

            // Create a transform with a translation of 0.2 meters in front of the camera
            var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
            translation.columns.3.z = -0.2
            let transform = simd_mul(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)

            // Add a new anchor to the session
            let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: transform)
            sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need to record only frames (as with `AVCaptureSession`, not "real" 3D scene with `SCNNodes`), just get them as `ARFrame.capturedImage` in `updateAtTime` delegate function of `SCNSceneRenderer`:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    createMovieWriterOnce(frame: session.currentFrame)
    appendFrameWithMetadaToMovie(frame: session.currentFrame)
}
```

I haven't found a way to get frame size from `ARSession`, so `MovieWriter` waits for first frame to setup size:

```
func createMovieWriterOnce(frame: ARFrame?) {
    if(frame == nil) { return }
    DispatchQueue.once(token: "SimplestMovieWriter.constructor") {
        movieWriter = SimplestMovieWriter(frameWidth: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(frame!.capturedImage), frameHeight: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(frame!.capturedImage))
    }
}
```

And each next `CVPixelBuffer` is fed to `MovieWriter`:

```
func appendFrameWithMetadaToMovie(frame: ARFrame?) {
    if(!isVideoRecording || frame == nil) { return }
    let interestingPoints = frame?.rawFeaturePoints?.points
    movieWriter.appendBuffer(buffer: (frame?.capturedImage)!, withMetadata: interestingPoints)
}
```

`MovieWriter` is custom class with `AVAssetWriter`, `AVAssetWriterInput` and `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`.

You can save video without audio, then use `AVAssetExportSession` to add anything you want (audio, subtitles, metadata):

```
let composition = AVMutableComposition()
...
let trackVideo = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
let videoFileAsset = AVURLAsset(url: currentURL!, options: nil)
let videoFileAssetTrack = videoFileAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]

// add audio track here
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! That's exactly what I ned, I didn't need nodes :)